# input type date required not working: the form is still submitted

Tags: html, validation, form-submit

I have an input date like this:

```
<input id="date_1" required="1" name="date" type="date">
```

But the form is still submitted.

I tried with this js:

```
document.getElementById('date_1').required = true;
```

but none change.
The strange thing is that jquery considers this input "valid".

**UPDATE**
I do not how but the input seems to have a value (not shown in the input).
I am investigating on it.

Comment: If you inspect in your browser devtools, is the input required set to true?

Comment: Could you update with the form HTML you are using?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser what you mean? the devtools browser show me the html and I see the input does have the required attribute set to 1

Comment: Did you put your input into <form></form> ?

Answer (score 1):

`required` is a [boolean value,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) it should be just:

```js
<input id="date_1" required name="date" type="date">
```

Comment: same, the form is still submitted

Comment: Then I would expect there to be a problem with the `<form>`

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. I've tried it on Chrome, I.E., Edge and Firefox and it works for me.

**Code:**

```
<form action="">
     <input type="date" required name="date" id="date" />
     <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

Also **required** doesn't need a value, you can simply type it as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can set required as true. Note: Required is a boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have stated, the required attribute is a boolean and should just be declared with a value, details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Note that earlier versions of IE don't support this.
Perhaps posting more of your html will allows us help more.